# How can I turn R code from an old package's function into a working function in the current version of R

Tags: r, function, r-raster

I typically use Matlab and am only an amateur when it comes to R. I have been trying to use someone elses code from 2011 and it is calling for  a function called 'xyValues'. I have found that this used to be function within the Raster package (version 1.5.8) but no longer appears in the current version. 
The old raster package is incompatible with newer versions of R. I have tried downgrading R but then that causes other issues.

I have downloaded the tar.gz file and extracted the code for the xyValues function. I tried to paste it into my newer version of the Raster package, but unsurprisingly, it didn't work.
Is there an easy way for me to turn the code for this function into an actual function that I can save and then use (as if I wrote the function myself)? I could do this easily in matlab, but it seems the process for writing a function is a little different in R and I don't really know where to start? I see some variations of this question on this site, but I'm wondering if it is possible for a new user of R (like me) to be able to do what I am suggesting. Perhaps it is only possible if you have a lot of knowledge regarding R. This is the code I extracted:

```
# Author: Robert J. Hijmans
# contact: r.hijmans@gmail.com
# Date : November 2008
# Version 0.9
# Licence GPL v3


if (!isGeneric("xyValues")) {
  setGeneric("xyValues", function(object, xy, ...)
    standardGeneric("xyValues"))
}   


setMethod("xyValues", signature(object='Raster', xy='SpatialPoints'), 
          function(object, xy, method='simple', buffer=NULL, fun=NULL, na.rm=TRUE,...) { 
            callGeneric(object, coordinates(xy),  method, buffer, fun, na.rm, ...)
          } 
)


setMethod("xyValues", signature(object='Raster', xy='data.frame'), 
          function(object, xy, method='simple', buffer=NULL, fun=NULL, na.rm=TRUE,...) { 
            callGeneric(object, as.matrix(xy), method, buffer, fun, na.rm, ...)
          } 
)


setMethod("xyValues", signature(object='Raster', xy='vector'), 
          function(object, xy, method='simple', buffer=NULL, fun=NULL, na.rm=TRUE, ...) { 
            if (length(xy) == 2) {
              callGeneric(object, matrix(xy, ncol=2), method, buffer, fun, na.rm,  ...)
            } else {
              stop('xy coordinates should be a two-column matrix or data.frame, or a vector of two numbers.')
            }
          } )


setMethod("xyValues", signature(object='RasterLayer', xy='matrix'), 
          function(object, xy, method='simple', buffer=NULL, fun=NULL, na.rm=TRUE, ...) { 

            if (dim(xy)[2] != 2) {
              stop('xy has wrong dimensions; it should have 2 columns' )
            }

            if (! is.null(buffer)) {
              if (method != 'simple') { warning('method argument is ignored when a buffer is used') }
              return( .xyvBuf(object, xy, buffer, fun, na.rm=na.rm) )
            }

            if (method=='bilinear') {
              return(.bilinearValue(object, xy))
            } else if (method=='simple') {
              cells <- cellFromXY(object, xy)
              return(.readCells(object, cells))
            } else {
              stop('invalid method argument. Should be simple or bilinear.')
            }
          } 
)   


setMethod("xyValues", signature(object='RasterStack', xy='matrix'), 
          function(object, xy, method='simple', buffer=NULL, fun=NULL, na.rm=TRUE, ...) { 
            .xyvStackBrick(object, xy, method, buffer, fun, na.rm, ...)
          } )

setMethod("xyValues", signature(object='RasterBrick', xy='matrix'), 
          function(object, xy, method='simple', buffer=NULL, fun=NULL, na.rm=TRUE, ...) { 
            .xyvStackBrick(object, xy, method, buffer, fun, na.rm, ...)
          } )


.xyvStackBrick <- function(object, xy, method='simple', buffer=NULL, fun=NULL, na.rm=TRUE, ...) { 

  dots <- list(...)
  layer <- dots$layer
  n <- dots$nl
  nls <- nlayers(object)

  if (is.null(layer)) { layer <- 1 } 
  if (is.null(n)) { n <- nls } 
  layer <- min(max(1, round(layer)), nls)
  n <- min(max(1, round(n)), nls-layer+1)

  if (dim(xy)[2] != 2) {
    stop('xy has wrong dimensions; there should be 2 columns only' )
  }

  if (! is.null(buffer)) {
    if (method != 'simple') { warning('method argument is ignored when a buffer is used') }
    return( .xyvBuf(object, xy, buffer, fun, na.rm, layer=layer, n=n) )
  }

  if (method == 'bilinear') {
    result <- .bilinearValue(object, xy, layer=layer, n=n)
    return(result)      

  } else if (method=='simple') {

    cells <- cellFromXY(object, xy)
    return( cellValues(object, cells, layer=layer, n=n) )

  } else {
    stop('invalid method argument. Should be simple or bilinear.')
  }
}
```

As a followup to this question, initially, when I wanted to see if this function was in my raster package I tried typing `help(xyValues)` and nothing came up (because it didn't exist). However, when I try this for functions that DO exist within the package, they too, are not showing up. Does this mean my raster package isn't loaded correctly?

The piece of code I am using with the function in it is:

```
elevgrid <- xyValues(elev,cbind(xygrid[,2],xygrid[,1]))
```

where `elev` is a Formal class Rasterlayer of size 920x1000 and `xygrid` is 4800 obs of 2 variables (x y coordinates)

I tried using:

```
> source("C:/Users/Documents/raster/R/xyValues.R")
```

but I got all these errors:

```
in method for ‘xyValues’ with signature ‘object="Raster",xy="data.frame"’: no definition for class “Raster”
in method for ‘xyValues’ with signature ‘object="Raster",xy="vector"’: no definition for class “Raster”
in method for ‘xyValues’ with signature ‘object="RasterLayer",xy="matrix"’: no definition for class “RasterLayer”
in method for ‘xyValues’ with signature ‘object="RasterStack",xy="matrix"’: no definition for class “RasterStack”
in method for ‘xyValues’ with signature ‘object="RasterBrick",xy="matrix"’: no definition for class “RasterBrick”
Warning message:
in method for ‘xyValues’ with signature ‘object="Raster",xy="SpatialPoints"’: no definition for classes “Raster”, “SpatialPoints”
```

I tried the `getvalues` and `approxNA` functions and got this:

```
> elevgrid <- getValues(elev,cbind(xygrid[,2],xygrid[,1]))
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘getValues’ for signature ‘"RasterLayer", "matrix", "missing"’
> elevgrid <- approxNA(elev)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘approxNA’ for signature ‘"RasterLayer"’
```

Comment: Looks like you need to use `xyValues` instead of  `xyvalues`

Comment: @RobertHijmans Thanks for taking the time to respond. I am using xyValues. I am using a newer version of your raster package which doesn't appear to have this function? At least when I type: **lsf.str("package:raster")** I don't see it in the list?

Comment: In the code: `getValues(elev,cbind(xygrid[,2],xygrid[,1]))` if you want all the data just declare the raster: `getValues(elev)`, that will bring back everything. For `xyValues` sourcing; that error means you haven't loaded the raster package. Use `library(raster)` then source those files. Don't forget to source the other files too, otherwise `xyValues` will not work as it doesn't have it's helper functions.

Comment: @Badger re:the sourcing. Even when I call the raster package with library(Raster) and each of the helper functions, I am still getting this error.:
'Error in setMethod("xyValues", signature(object = "Raster", xy = "SpatialPoints"),  : 
  no existing definition for function ‘xyValues’'

Comment: I realize I didn't explain your last error here, as I mention below, `approxNA` only works on raster stacks or bricks, so the raster layer error is because you are not using a stack or brick, which is fine, because you don't have a stack or brick.

Comment: Can you update everything new that you've done? Having called `library(raster)` then sourcing the R scripts you need should solve it, so far as I can see.

Comment: Hey are you trying to extract the cell values for certain locations? If yes, check out `?extract`

Comment: Badger is right. Use `extract`

Comment: @ Badger Thank you for all your effort. That's exactly what I needed...but I have learned a bit more about R along the way!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the xyValyes method extracted values from a raster using points (xy coordinates). This function has been replaced with `extract`. So instead of

```
library(raster)
xyValues(x, xy, ...)
```

You should be able to do

```
extract(x, xy, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ways you can address this issue.

## First and foremost:

Do you actually need the old function to do the work, or can it be done with a newer generation function? I'm not really clear what you're trying to do, so I can't suggest a better function.

Based on my assumptions through what you're doing and the help documentation for `xyValues()` this is my guess.
First you need to use `approxNA()`(*requires stack*) this performs the interpolation as it would in `xyValues()` to fill in `NA`s in your raster. Then you need to turn it into a `data.frame` or a `vector` of values. This can be done with either `as.data.frame()` or `getValues()`.
If you do not have NAs you need to fill, you can just pull the values with `getValues()` or `as.data.frame()`

```
dat.r <- raster(matrix(nrow = 100,ncol = 100,sample(x = 1:1000,size = 10000,replace = T)))
dat.vector <- getValues(dat.r)
dat.dataframe <- as.data.frame(dat.r)
```

*If you do have NAs* - I found a suggestion here: [Fill in gaps (e.g. not single cells) of NA values in raster using a neighborhood analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45641168/fill-in-gaps-e-g-not-single-cells-of-na-values-in-raster-using-a-neighborhood)

```
## Add in some NAs
dat.r[sample(1:10000,1000)] <- NA
fill.na <- function(x) {
  center = 0.5 + (width*width/2) 
  if( is.na(x)[center] ) {
    return( round(mean(x, na.rm=TRUE),0) )
  } else {
    return( round(x[center],0) )
  }
}  
  
width = 9
r2 <- focal(dat.r, w = matrix(1,width,width), fun = fill.na, 
            pad = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE)
dat.vector <- getValues(r2)
dat.dataframe<- as.data.frame(r2)
```

### Second:

You can just source everything you need from the unpacked tar.

```
source("~/raster_1.5-8/raster/R/xyValues.R")
source("~/raster_1.5-8/raster/R/xyValuesBuffer.R")
source("~/raster_1.5-8/raster/R/bilinearValue.R")
source("~/raster_1.5-8/raster/R/readCells.R")
```

~ is the directory to where you have unpacked raster_1.5-8
A quick noted on why there are 4 scripts and not just the 1 you are after. Any function with a leading . is a hidden function that gets loaded with the package but is not explictly executable. As you are not instantiating the package, you need these helper functions.

#### Third ***Not Recommended***:

You can attempt to install and older version of the package following the instructions here. https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/219949047-Installing-older-versions-of-packages
The code you would need is:

```
require(devtools)
install_version("raster", version = "1.5-8", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org/")
```

This may result in problems down the line if you are trying to use current generation functions, so I would not recommend this method

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried (1) and (2) above and have edited my question to show the results.